# How to convert epoch time with nanoseconds to human-readable?

Tags: python, datetime, time, epoch, nanotime

I have a timestamp in epoch time with nanoseconds - e.g. `1360287003083988472` nanoseconds since 1970-01-01.

The Python datetime objects and conversion methods only support up to millisecond precision.

Is there an easy way to convert this epoch time into human-readable time?

Comment: @abarnert I don't think so. This question deals with converting a number to a human-readable string, whereas that one is trying to convert from a string to a `datetime` object.

Comment: @ethg242: That question is sort of all over the place, but it comes down to the same thing: `datetime` doesn't handle nanoseconds, so you have to do the math/stringops yourself. Maybe it's fine to have one question about `strptime` and another about `strftime`.

Comment: this is one turned out better than the duplicate

Comment: @abarnert Have you actually look at the answers on the other question? Lol. For some reason, naxa is right, the answers on this one turned out better, no idea why.

Comment: @victorhooi: Yes, sometimes dups do turn out better than the original. That means you shouldn't ignore a question just because it might be a dup (notice that one of the two answers here is mine), but it doesn't mean we shouldn't mark dups.

Comment: Python's `datetime.datetime()` has microsecond support for the fractions and thus microsecond instead of millisecond precision.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

First, convert it to a [`datetime`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime) object with second precision (floored, not rounded):

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(1360287003083988472 // 1000000000)
>>> dt
datetime.datetime(2013, 2, 7, 17, 30, 3)
```

Then to make it human-readable, use the [`strftime()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) method on the  object you get back:

```
>>> s = dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
>>> s
'2013-02-07 17:30:03'
```

Finally, add back in the nanosecond precision:

```
>>> s += '.' + str(int(1360287003083988472 % 1000000000)).zfill(9)
>>> s
'2013-02-07 17:30:03.083988472'
```

Comment: My problem here is that by using `1360287003083988472 // 1000000000`, you're at risk of loosing valuable information. One can get a human-readable format by using `datetime.fromtimestamp(1360287003083988472 / 1000000000)` instead.

Comment: @r02. Converting a uint64 to float can lose a lot of valuable information too. One has 64 bits of precision, the other effectively 53.

Answer (score 17):

Actually, Python's `datetime` methods handle *microsecond* precision, not *millisecond*:

```
>>> nanos = 1360287003083988472
>>> secs = nanos / 1e9
>>> dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(secs)
>>> dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')
'2013-02-07T17:30:03.083988'
```

But if you actually *need* nanoseconds, that still doesn't help. Your best bet is to write your own wrapper:

```
def format_my_nanos(nanos):
    dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(nanos / 1e9)
    return '{}{:03.0f}'.format(dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f'), nanos % 1e3)
```

This gives me:

```
'2013-02-07T17:30:03.083988472'
```

Of course you could have done the same thing even if Python didn't do sub-second precision at all…

```
def format_my_nanos(nanos):
    dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(nanos / 1e9)
    return '{}.{:09.0f}'.format(dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'), nanos % 1e9)
```

Comment: Unix epoch time is UTC so `datetime.utcfromtimestamp(secs)` will get the correct timezone, fromtimestamp will use the system timezone https://stackoverflow.com/a/72225603/603653

Answer (score 4):

It should be noted that ubiquitous libraries `numpy` and `pandas` can handle Unix time in nanoseconds without further preparation:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

unix_ns = 1360287003083988472

np.datetime64(unix_ns, 'ns') # need to specify unit here
# Out[4]: numpy.datetime64('2013-02-08T01:30:03.083988472')

pd.Timestamp(unix_ns) # pd.Timestamp defaults to ns
# Out[5]: Timestamp('2013-02-08 01:30:03.083988472')

# alternatively (also e.g. for list input):
pd.to_datetime(unix_ns)
# Out[6]: Timestamp('2013-02-08 01:30:03.083988472')
```

numpy / pandas datetime resembles UTC if you do not set a time zone. In vanilla Python datetime, it's *local time*.