# Convert nanoseconds to timestamp in Python

Tags: python, date, time

I know it is possible to convert nanoseconds in java to a timestamp like this:

```
import java.util.Date;
 public class DateDemo {

  public static void main(String args[]) {
  // Instantiate a Date object

    long i = 1462352019029395103L;
  // display time and date using toString()
   Date date = new Date(i / 1000000);

  System.out.println(date.toString());
  }
 }
```

This make: Wed May 04 08:53:39 UTC 2016

While in Python the output is:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(1462352019029395103 // 1000000000)
>>> s = dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
>>> s
'2016-05-04 10:53:39'
```

The difference is 2 hours in python. I don't know exactly why. I read some earlier posts that Python couldn't convert nanoseconds. Is there any way I get the accurate timestamp in python?

Comment: The difference is UTC and your local time zone.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15649942/how-to-convert-epoch-time-with-nanoseconds-to-human-readable

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`utcfromtimestamp`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp) to make it equivalent with the datetime in Java:

```
>>> dt = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(1462352019029395103 // 1000000000)
>>> dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
'2016-05-04 08:53:39'
```

---

Reference:

[Coordinated Universal Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time)

'