# Unix time to real time in microseconds python

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, time, unix-timestamp

I have tried the following and got the error:

```
>>> datetime.utcfromtimestamp(1539065539).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
'2018-10-09 6:12:19.000000'.
>>> datetime.utcfromtimestamp(int(1539065539013987670)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
>>> datetime.utcfromtimestamp(153906553901).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

I think the number is going beyond the size of `int` data type. Hence this error is coming. How to get rid of it and have the correct answer in the microseconds, which I am expecting.

Comment: It's not that "the number is going beyond the size of an int" but that you are calling the function with the wrong data. "The unix time stamp is a way to track time as a running total of seconds. This count starts at the Unix Epoch on January 1st, 1970 at UTC" so you must call the utcfromtimestamp(timestamp) with a valid timestamp in seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Divide the value (which actually seems to be nanoseconds) by 1e9 to get seconds, which you can pass to `utcfromtimestamp`.

```
>>> datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(1539065539013987670 / 1e9)
datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 9, 6, 12, 19, 13988)
```

Comment: This is nice and compact answer sir.. thank you

Answer (score 1):

This is answered on [Python - Convert epoch time with nanoseconds to human-readable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15649942/python-convert-epoch-time-with-nanoseconds-to-human-readable)

```
>>> datetime.utcfromtimestamp(1539065539013987670/1000000000).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
'2018-10-09 06:12:19.013988'
```

Comment: This is an awesome answer too....