# datetime.fromtimestamp() - returns my local timezone instead of GMT

Tags: python, datetime, gmt

I have a problem converting `timestamp` to `GMT`. As far as I know, the `timestamp` is allways in `GMT` time so I expect `datetime.fromtimestamp` returning `GMT` or timezone-aware datetime but it returns my local (Bratislava/Prague) datetime.

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1566720000)
datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 25, 10, 0)
```

But according to [Epoch Converter](https://www.epochconverter.com/) it is

**GMT: Sunday, August 25, 2019 8:00:00 AM**

EDIT: `datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1566720000).tzinfo` returns nothing so it is not tz aware.

Do you know where is the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

fromtimestamp() returns the local date and time. If it needs to be tz-aware, the parameter tz must be specified:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp

> Return the local date and time corresponding to the POSIX timestamp,
>   such as is returned by time.time(). If optional argument tz is None or
>   not specified, the timestamp is converted to the platform’s local date
>   and time, and the returned datetime object is naive.

If you need the a datetime object in UTC, use utcfromtimestamp instead:

```
datetime.utcfromtimestamp(timestamp)
```

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you want [utcfromtimestamp](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp)

```
>>> datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(1566720000)
datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 25, 8, 0)
```

> Keep in mind this still returns a naive datetime object

Comment: If you want to avoid wanings because of the naive date I solved that with: datetime.fromtimestamp((datetime.now(timezone.utc).timestamp() + next_level_info['upgrade_time']), timezone.utc)

Answer (score 4):

It is not a good idea to use `datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp()`. It returns a naive datetime object (without time zone information) which would be interpreted by many functions as `datetime` in your local time zone! It is much better to use time zone aware objects.

The following code returns time zone aware `datetime` in the UTC time zone.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1566720000, datetime.timezone.utc)
datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 25, 8, 0, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```