# Converting integer datetime to datetime format

Tags: python, matplotlib, datetime

I convert the numpy array of datetime to a list but i need to reverse them into datetime format.

```
> v_date
[1642636800000000000,
 1649203200000000000,
 1649462400000000000,
 1650326400000000000,
...
 1668816000000000000,
 1669593600000000000,
 1671753600000000000]
```

the xaxis of matplotlib chart need to be **small integer or has the datetime format**. it raise this error: `OverflowError: int too big to convert`

Comment: What code are you trying that gives you that error?

Comment: Which datetimes are these numbers and why?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I think the format is nanoseconds 0:00 UTC on January 1, 1970, since that's a form of the very-commonly-used Unix time, and the first timestamp (I didn't check the others) is therefore 0:00 UTC on January 20, 2022.

Comment: I've added a [note](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75823296/10197418) on numpy and pandas to the linked dupe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
import pandas as pd

v_date = [1642636800000000000,
          1649203200000000000,
          1649462400000000000,
          1650326400000000000,
          1668816000000000000,
          1669593600000000000,
          1671753600000000000]

out = pd.to_datetime(v_date)
```

Output:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2022-01-20', '2022-04-06', '2022-04-09', '2022-04-19', '2022-11-19', '2022-11-28', '2022-12-23'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```